# What could be wrong when a crack opens in the grout between tile and ceiling when installing a tension pole shower caddy?

Tags: bathroom, shower

I just got an [OXO corner shower caddy](https://youtu.be/e8PAHoYzPaI?feature=shared&t=9s), and to stay in place, it relies on pressure created when it extends upwards as you engage a lock on the pole. When I engaged the lock, it extended as it should, but a crack opened up in the grout where the tile meets the ceiling. Did I extend it too long? Or is there something wrong with the tile, ceiling, or grout?

[image: Prior to engaging the lock, no crack]

[image: After engaging the lock, crack appears]

Answer (score 5):

What you've got there isn't a normal occurance. You shouldn't be able to separate the ceiling from the two walls. It could be a bad framing job. You've had a few problems like this posted in other questions. Try applying more pressure in that corner to see if the crack gets larger. If it remains the same, you probably took up the slack between the two surfaces. Then just get some caulk and fill in the crack. That should not be grout up there because there is a change in planes that would require caulk that "gives" where grout won't "give". Monitor this to see if it gets worse and then come back here.

Answer (score 2):

Those tension pole units are damaging unless you get it right on a ceiling joist. Better avoid them and hang a caddy from a screw in the wall preferably into a stud.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with celing or the walls.

But they are not one continuous unit.

You can lift the celing with enough force.

That is what happened here.

If you can find the celing beams use those.

Comment: Exactly what is the OP to use the ceiling beams for?